# Return Bit in UDF

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, user-defined-functions

This is more specific to MS SQL (>2008, but mostly version agnostic).

I'm looking to simplify the check for a Stored Procedure in SQL Server.
What I would like to end up with is something like this:

```
IF (dbo.PROC_EXISTS(N'MY_STORED_PROC_NAME') = 1)
    DROP PROCEDURE MY_STORED_PROC_NAME
GO
```

What I currently have:

```
SELECT
CAST(
    CASE 
        WHEN EXISTS (
            SELECT  *
            FROM    sys.objects
            WHERE   object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'GET_ALT_SCHEDULE')
                        AND type IN (N'P', N'PC')
        ) 
        THEN 'TRUE' 
        ELSE 'FALSE'
        END 
AS BIT
)

RETURNS 1 -- TRUE
RETURNS 0 -- FALSE
```

When I place this code inside of a function, it does not work because I cannot return a value that comes from a select statement.

```
CREATE FUNCTION PROC_EXISTS(@SPName NVARCHAR)
    RETURNS BIT
AS

BEGIN

DECLARE @Answer BIT

SET @Answer = SELECT  -- Incorrect syntax near 'SELECT'
    CAST(
        CASE 
            WHEN EXISTS (
                SELECT  *
                FROM    sys.objects
                WHERE   object_id = OBJECT_ID(@SPName)
                           AND type IN (N'P', N'PC')
            ) 
            THEN 1 
            ELSE 0
            END 
    AS BIT
    )
RETURN @Answer
END
```

Could someone provide some insight into what's going on? and if you can a solution to how this function could be composed to return what I'm looking for (As per the first code block)

Or perhaps a function is not appropriate for this scenario. But please state why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about just using `object_id()`?

```
if object_id(N'dbo.proc_name') is not null 
drop procedure dbo.proc_name;
```

---

To correct your function code:

Your input is specified as `nvarchar` without a size, so it defaults to a length of 1. Change it to `sysname` instead.

Remove `select` as you are using `set` already. Alternatively, you could remove `set` and use `select @Answer = cast ...`.

```
create function proc_exists (@spname sysname)
returns bit as
begin;
  declare @Answer bit;
  set @Answer = case when exists (
      select *
      from sys.objects
      where object_id = object_id(@spname) 
        and type in (N'P', N'PC')
      ) 
      then 1 else 0 end;
  return @Answer;
end;
go
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/EYWVBY20177

Comment: Thanks! this is exactly what I was looking for. I'll probably just use object_id() is not null from now on. That's what I was really looking for. Appreciate the ore in- depth explanation on the function too. It is great to see that in action.